# Is it possible to have fall-back for empty values in a LINQ query considering locale?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, excel, locale

I'm creating a C# .NET 3.5 website. In this website some content is read from an XML file. This XML file is saved from an Excel file, so basically the Excel is a kind of content management system (I cannot use a database in this situation). I am using LINQ to XML to get collections of the content objects so I can work with them on the webforms. I am a just starting with LINQ, but I know the basics like grouping and ordering.

I am using the following code to read the content into a collection (in this case a list of video's):

```
string path = String.Format(server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Content.{0}.xml"), culture);
XDocument source = cache.Get(path);

bool boolValue = false;

var query =
    from video in source.Descendants("Video")
    where video.Attribute("Id").Value != null

    /* Temporary values */
    let featured = video.Attribute("IsFeatured").Value

    select new Video
    {
        Culture = culture, 
        Id = video.Attribute("Id").Value, 
        Name = video.Element("Name").Value,
        Description = video.Element("Description").Value,
        Category = video.Element("Category").Value,
        Url = video.Element("Url").Value,
        IsFeatured = Boolean.TryParse(featured, out boolValue) ? boolValue : false, 
        Tags = video.Element("Tags").Value.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray()
    };

return query.ToList();
```

In the current situation there is one xml file per culture. A mayor drawback is that it will result in a lot of redundant values. To make it more manageable, i will have just one xml file.

I would like to create a situation where rows with the same id share content so I don't have to add redundant values. Is it possible to have a "fall-back" for the empty values?

**Example: creating the xml(excel) file**

If I want to read Swiss German content the query will look for values where the locale is 'de-ch'. If there are still empty values the query will look for a 'higher' locale, in this case 'de', and last if there are still empty values it will take them from the default locale, which is 'en'.

Let's say I have a Product object.
It has a name, a description and a price.

**Start with English (en)**

I will start with the culture 'en', because this is my standard culture.
In the excel I would create a row:

- Locale = en
- Name = Product 1
- Description= English description
- Price = 100

**Then German (de)**
Then i want a translation in German, so I add another row, but I leave the Name and price empty, because there are the same.

- Locale = de
- Name =
- Description= German description
- Price =

**Then Swiss German (de-ch)**
Here i only want to add the price, because it has a different currency.

- Locale = de-ch
- Name =
- Description =
- Price = 222

**The result I am aiming for in LINQ**

When the culture would be de-ch, the returning object in LINQ will have the following values:

- Locale = de-ch
- Name = Product 1 (from en)
- Description = German description (from de)
- Price = 222 (from de-ch)

I think I will be able to do it in normal C# with some loops, but how would you do this in Linq? Maybe someone can give some direction how I can achieve this in LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interest of clarity for whomever is going to be taking this over I would suggest loading it via linq how you have it into a **data structure** that can handle this form of fallback.

There will be no or little cost compared to any frankenstein approach Linq will probably need.

And in my experience I havent' seen anything that will do this. Somebody else might have ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I would like to keep the code clear so I'll go with that. I'll just load the xml with LINQ and then I'll figure something out in plain C# to do the fallback.